# Display image based on random string from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a list of strings in two arrays truth & dare that are loaded from a plist then randomised and displayed to the user in a label these could be truth or dares. I would like to display a image for both truth and dare when each one is displayed dependant on which array it is loaded from.

As i load the plist file into an array on load im not sure how to go about doing this? Im very new to xcode and am excited at the progress im making so far however.

This is the full code from my .m file

```
   @interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@synthesize plistArray;


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self becomeFirstResponder];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];






    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                      @"data" ofType:@"plist"];







    if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff"] isEqualToString:@"YES"] && [[defaults objectForKey:@"dareonoff"] isEqualToString:@"YES"]  ) {

            self.text.text =@"Are you ready for this?";



            NSDictionary *plistDict1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            NSArray * plistArray1 = plistDict1[@"truth"];



            NSDictionary *plistDict2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            NSArray *plistArray2 = plistDict2[@"dare"];

            self.plistArray = [[plistArray1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:plistArray2] mutableCopy];

        }

        else if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff"] isEqualToString:@"YES"] ) {

            self.text.text =@"I hope you are feeling brave!";



            NSDictionary *plistDict3 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

            NSArray *plistArray3 = plistDict3[@"truth"] ;

            self.plistArray = [plistArray3 mutableCopy];


            NSLog(@"%@", plistArray);


        }

        else if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"dareonoff"] isEqualToString:@"YES"] ) {

            self.text.text =@"This could be interesting!";


            NSDictionary *plistDict4 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

            NSMutableArray *plistArray4 = plistDict4[@"dare"];

            self.plistArray = [plistArray4 mutableCopy];


            NSLog(@"%@", plistArray);


        }
        else {
            self.text.text =@"Please turn on Truth or Dare";


        }



}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}


- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Do your thing after shaking device

    if ([plistArray count] == 0) {
        self.text.text = @"Please Upgrade for more";
    }
    else    {
        ////display random quote from array
        int randV = arc4random() % self.plistArray.count;


        self.text.text = self.plistArray[randV];
        [self.plistArray removeObjectAtIndex:randV];

    }

   }



-(IBAction)modal:(id)sender{

}

- (IBAction)container:(id)sender {
}











- (IBAction)shownext:(id)sender {






    if ([plistArray count] == 0) {
               self.text.text = @"Please Upgrade for more";
            }
        else    {
        ////display random quote from array
        int randV = arc4random() % self.plistArray.count;


            self.text.text = self.plistArray[randV];
            [self.plistArray removeObjectAtIndex:randV];

            }

}




@end
```

And here is my plist structure there will be alot more data added here when finished tho
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tough to understand the code, so I'll state this in general terms.  If you have two arrays of strings (maybe your truth array and dare array), and you have a string that the user selected (this is the part that's unclear in your code -- is it self.text.text?)  Let's just call it `selectedString`, then you can test:

```
if ([self.truthArray containsObject:selectedString]) {
    // selectedString is from the truth array
} else if ([self.dareArray containsObject:selectedString]) {
    // selectedString is from the dare array
} else {
    // it's in neither array.  maybe this is an error
}
```